# Git staging shows Deleted file

Tags: git, github

I'm new to GIT . When I add a new file to local maven project and delete it without commit and push to git repository. Still the file is shown in Git staging eventhough the file is deleted physically in the local machine. Why is it so?
Do i need to commit and push the file to git repo eventhough I just created it locally and deleted immediately?

Answer (score 0):

If the file has been made part of the repo, either staged or committed, and you want to delete it, you have to do it through git.

```
git rm path-to-the-file
```

Comment: No i haven't made the file as part of repo. I just created a new file locally and deleted it before commiting it to repo..But still the file is shown in git staging ?

Comment: Did you issue a command similar to `git add .`? Or `git add some-folder/`? maybe the file is contained in that folder.

Comment: No I am using eclipse and created a new file using eclipse and deleted it using the editor. I haven't issued any command. Still why it is showing in git staging If the file is not present in repo and i deleted it locally.

Comment: IDEs are sometimes configured to index automatically files that are created inside folders that are already indexed. Most likely this is what happened. A reason for me to not use IDEs and stick to the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the source folder in GIT Bash,

Step 1: **git status**      --> check the files status

If the file is not indexed, then step 2 or else step 3.

{EDIT} Please be careful with step 2, which will erase all the files which are not indexed. Check the files before executing this step.

Step 2: **git clean -f**    --> Remove the files that are not indexed.

Step 3: **git rm file-path**  --> Manually delete the file if indexed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Step 2 is dangerous, he might not want to erase all the local files. This could be sample data, images, etc.

Comment: True..! but if the files are not indexed which can be deleted. Thanks for that..will update the answer

Comment: @vinayveluri.. What actually happens if i issue step 2 command.

Answer (score 0):

The git index, ie the staging area, is maintained as a separate file system - the git object model, on top of your physical file system. Thus even if the file is deleted physically on your disk, it can still be well and alive in the index. (That's why its so hard to lose your work in git as long as you frequently stage or commit.)

In your case specifically, if the file is in the index, it must have been added there either by you issuing a variant of `git add` or by your IDE or other tools/scripts in your dev flow doing it in your stead.

You can remove the file from the index by running:

```
$ git rm --cached <file>
```

If you want to investigate the history of your file, how and when it was committed - if at all, you can do:

```
$ git log --follow <file>
```